# Stuck in the endless loop of installing packages in Julia, and can't find solution

Tags: julia

It seems I am stuck in an endless loop.
When adding one package, it says needing another, and when installing the other, it says need the prebvious one.
Installing Julia packages could be one of the most challanging task.

It shall be my 12th re-installation of Julia...

I am with Win10+Julia 1.5.2 + VS Code

[image: endless loop]

Comment: From Julia prompt try: `use Pkg; Pkg.update()`

Comment: Are you using Julia on Windows?

Comment: @Tarik Thanks, but I got another error `ERROR: expected package `CUDA [052768ef]` to be registered`, and Yes, I am with Win10 +Julia==1.5.2, + VSCODE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registered packages should be installed without giving the git url, use just the package name:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add Juno
   Updating registry at `C:\Users\mittel\.julia\registries\General`
  Resolving package versions...
  Installed Media ─ v0.5.0
  Installed Juno ── v0.8.4
Updating `C:\Users\mittel\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [e5e0dc1b] + Juno v0.8.4
Updating `C:\Users\mittel\.julia\environments\v1.5\Manifest.toml`
  [e5e0dc1b] + Juno v0.8.4
  [e89f7d12] + Media v0.5.0
  [9abbd945] + Profile
```

everything should work automatically

if you still have problems, try deleting your `Manifest.toml`.

If it still does not help delete `.julia` package repository.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I have lot of manifest.toml. Which one do you mention?

Comment: the one where you're trying to install the package, in my case `.julia\environments\v1.5\Manifest.toml`

Comment: when my installs become a mess, I sometimes delete the whole `.julia` folder and start all my package installs over

Comment: I am thinking if I should deletel all `.julia`.....

Comment: you can, you won't lose anything if you didn't put anything there (if you didn't modify `dev` packages)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I just found my choper and it is still sharp. Hope the new installation won't take too long.

Comment: The location of `Manifest.toml` that is being loaded by default can be found by running the command: `using Pkg;Pkg.activate()`